# Proper project structuring

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I've recently started as the sole developer on a Django project. I'm currently working on updating an endpoint to including validation for incoming PDF documents.

The simple validation function follows:

```py
def is_valid_certification(stream: BytesIO) -> bool:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(stream)
    page: PageObject
    for page in pdf.pages:
        if page.extractText().find(<search string>) != -1:
            return True
    return False
```

My question is, where is the most pythonic place to store this bit of code? Keeping all the logic within the POST handler seems messy and it's not generic enough to be considered a utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the fat model concept and have this function in the model that is responsible for this.

You could also create a services.py file in your app for functions and services that are specific to that particular app.
Any functions that are generic to the the project can go into the app named after project

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single correct answer for this, but I find that as my `views.py` files grow, the best way to keep them lean is just to move the business logic to other files as makes sense. Code doesn't necessarily **have** to be reusable to be abstracted; sometimes you just don't want a file to be 2,000 lines long, and you want a logical separation of functionality (e.g., `views.py` really just focuses on collecting data for rendering and all the heavy lifting is done in other modules).

For larger apps, especially with a lot of admin site customization, I'll often have the following files for a single app:

- admin_form_processing.py
- admin_forms.py
- admin_inline_forms.py
- admin_utils.py
- form_processing.py
- forms.py
- urls.py
- utils.py
- views.py
- some_file_that_processes_view_logic_1.py
- some_file_that_processes_view_logic_2.py
- etc.

I also often create an app called `core` or `utils` that has no urls/views but contains modules for general utility functionality (e.g., `form_utils.py` for form-related utilities that are used across multiple apps).